# How do I web scrape the sub-headers from this link?

Tags: python, excel, web-scraping

I've made a web scraper that scrapes data from pages that look like this (it scrapes the tables): https://www.techpowerup.com/gpudb/2/

The problem is that my program, for some reason, is only scraping the values, and not the subheaders. For instance, (click on the link), it only scrapes the "R420", "130nm", "160 million", etc. but not the "GPU Name", "Process Size", "Transistors" etc.

What do I add to the code to get it to scrape the subheaders? Here's my code:

```
import csv
import requests
import bs4
url = "https://www.techpowerup.com/gpudb/2"


#obtain HTML and parse through it
response = requests.get(url)
html = response.content
import sys
reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding('utf-8')
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(html, "lxml")
tables = soup.findAll("table")

#reading every value in every row in each table and making a matrix 
tableMatrix = []
for table in tables:
    list_of_rows = []
    for row in table.findAll('tr'):
        list_of_cells = []
        for cell in row.findAll('td'):
            text = cell.text.replace('&nbsp;', '')
            list_of_cells.append(text)
        list_of_rows.append(list_of_cells)
    tableMatrix.append((list_of_rows, list_of_cells))

#(YOU CAN PROBABLY IGNORE THIS)placeHolder used to avoid duplicate data from appearing in list 
placeHolder = 0
excelTable = []
for table in tableMatrix:
    for row in table:
        if placeHolder == 0:
            for entry in row:
                excelTable.append(entry)
            placeHolder = 1
        else:
            placeHolder = 0
    excelTable.append('\n')

for value in excelTable:
    print value
    print '\n'


#create excel file and write the values into a csv 
fl = open(str(count) + '.csv', 'w')
writer = csv.writer(fl)
for values in excelTable:
    writer.writerow(values)
fl.close()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you check the page source, those cells are header cells. So they are not using TD tags but TH tags. you may want to update your loop to include TH cells alongside TD cells.

Comment: When I add "th", so it becomes "findAll('td', 'th'), then it just doesn't show anything. Am I not supposed to add it there?

Comment: That is not correct usage of the findAll method. Please try this: `findAll( re.compile( 'td|th' ) )` Basically first parameter is the tag name. And second parameter is attributes. So what you write, tries to find a td tag with th attribute. (do not forget to import re)